# return queryset for specific fields to autocomplete formfields

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm not a django expert so I'm not sure if I'm just searching for the wrong thing but I'm trying to use django-autocomplete-light to autocomplete some fields on a modelform.

I have a model, Animal. Animal has several fields. My goal is to have a modelform that has autocomplete for several of these fields.

**forms.py**

```
class AnimalForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Animal
    fields = [
        'myfield'
    ]
    widgets = {
        'myfield': autocomplete.ListSelect2(
            url='myfield-autocomplete')
    }
```

**views.py:**

```
class MyfieldAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !

        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Animal.objects.none()
        qs = Animal.objects.filter().values('myfield')
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)
        return qs
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

I think because the Animal.objects.filter().values('myfield') returns the actual values, rather than a queryset.

If I change my queryset to:

```
class MyfieldAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !

        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Animal.objects.none()
        qs = Animal.objects.all()
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)
        return qs
```

This loads and my autocomplete field is populated with the name field of the Animal objects. Instead of name I want to be able to specify an arbitrary field.

update-
**error output:**

```
[28/Jan/2020 08:02:33] "GET /animals/add HTTP/1.1" 200 47686
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py:88: UnorderedObjectListWarning: Pagination may yield inconsistent results with an unordered object_list: <class 'animals.models.Animal'> QuerySet.
  allow_empty_first_page=allow_empty_first_page, **kwargs)
Internal Server Error: /operator-autocomplete/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response        
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response        
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\dal\views.py", line 50, in dispatch
    return super(ViewMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py", line 158, in get
    return self.render_to_response(context)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\dal_select2\views.py", line 61, in render_to_response
    'results': self.get_results(context) + create_option,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\dal_select2\views.py", line 26, in get_results
    } for result in context['object_list']
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\dal_select2\views.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    } for result in context['object_list']
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\dal\views.py", line 81, in get_result_value
    return str(result.pk)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want autocomplete for a particular field, instead of charfield make that field as foreignkey and implement autocomplete. For example if you have field named dog in Animal class,make a Dog class and in forms you can do it in following way

```
class AnimalCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dog = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Dog.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='dog_auto')
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = [
        'dog', ----,
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks, will investigate. Are you saying it definitively can't work for a charfield? I figured it would work for a charfield I suppose only because  I have implemented autocomplete for a taggablemanager field from django-taggit so I figured it could support arbitrary fields.